# How do i generate uniformly distributed random numbers in an interval [a, b] in c#

Tags: c#, statistics

I am trying to generate *uniformly distributed* random numbers in an interval `[a, b]` in c#. Can i use the

```
System.Random.Next(int min, int max)
```

method?

Comment: `random.Next(a, b + 1);` returns `int` (integer) random values uniformly distributed in `[a, b]`. If you want *floating point* values (`double`) then `a + (b - a) * random.NextDouble();`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should *create* a generator, e.g.

```
   // Simplest, but not thread safe
   private static Random random = new Random();
```

then if you want an *integer* value uniformly distributed in `[a, b]` range

```
   // b + 1 since upper bound is excluded
   int r = random.Next(a, b + 1);
```

if you require a *floating point* value (`double`) uniformly distributed in `[a, b)` range (border `b` will be excluded)

```
   double v = a + (b - a) * random.NextDouble();
```